# Can't reposition One textfiled in Java AWT

Tags: java, layout, button, frame, textfield

I am trying to make a login form using Java AWT. And i made it. But when i click button, all filed except "Pin" displayed in correct places. "Pin" was displayed in the same dimension as of "Name". I can't re-position the "Pin" text-field. why?
This is the code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Loginform extends Frame implements ActionListener
{ 
  Label l1=new Label("Name");
  Label l2=new Label("Street");
  Label l3=new Label("City");
  Label l4=new Label("Pin");
  Label l5=new Label("  ");
  Label l6=new Label("  ");
  Label l7=new Label("   ");
  Label l8=new Label("    ");
  TextField t1=new TextField();
  TextField t2=new TextField();
  TextField t3=new TextField();
  TextField t4=new TextField();
  Button b= new Button("Submit");
  public Loginform()
  { add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(l2);
    add(t2);
    add(l3);
    add(t3);
    add(l4);
    add(t4);
    add(b);
    add(l5);
    add(l6);
    add(l7);
    add(l8);
    l1.setBounds(20,45,70,20);
    t1.setBounds(180,45,200,20);
    l2.setBounds(20,95,70,20);
    t2.setBounds(180,95,200,20);

    l3.setBounds(20,135,70,20);
    t3.setBounds(180,135,200,20);
    l4.setBounds(20,175,70,20);
    t4.setBounds(180,175,200,20);

    l5.setBounds(20,300,70,20);
    l6.setBounds(20,320,70,20);
    l7.setBounds(20,340,70,20);
    l8.setBounds(20,360,70,20);

    b.setBounds(410,245,70,20);
    b.addActionListener(this);

    addWindowListener(new mwa());
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  { 
      l5.setText("Name: "+t1.getText());
      l6.setText("Street: "+t2.getText());
      l7.setText("City: "+t3.getText());
      l8.setText("Pin: "+t4.getText());

  }
  public static void main(String s[])
  {
     Loginform l=new Loginform();
    l.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    l.setTitle("REGISTRATION");
    l.setVisible(true);
  }
}
class mwa extends WindowAdapter
{ public mwa(){}
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
  { System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your Labels aren't showing up on your GUI because you are not respecting the default layout manager of the container that holds them. Since you're adding to a container (the Frame) that uses BorderLayout by default, only the last added Label will display. To show that this is so, change your actionPerformed to this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  l5.setText("Name: " + t1.getText());
  l6.setText("Street: " + t2.getText());
  l7.setText("City: " + t3.getText());
  l8.setText("Pin: " + t4.getText());

  System.out.println("l5: " + l5.getBounds());
  System.out.println("l6: " + l6.getBounds());
  System.out.println("l7: " + l7.getBounds());
  System.out.println("l8: " + l8.getBounds());

}
```

And you will see:

```
l5: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]
l6: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]
l7: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]
l8: java.awt.Rectangle[x=8,y=30,width=584,height=562]
```

For this code to work, the Labels must be displayed.  I suggest:

- Avoid setting the bounds or position or location of any component.
- Read the tutorials on how to use layout managers and use them help you create GUI's that display nicely and easily and are flexible and easily modifiable.
- Avoid using AWT and move over to Swing as it is more robust and powerful.
- Change your variable names to ones that describe their purpose, making your code self-commenting.

Comment: @Arjun: perhaps time to ask a new question then.

Comment: i edited the question. can you help me? i just did by setbound. except the pin, other fields displayed properly. please help

Comment: @Arjun: I cannot help you as you are completely ignoring all of my advice. The solution is *not* to call setBounds on anything but instead to learn how to use the layout managers.

Comment: i am not familiar with awt.thats why. then how to position them correctly without setbound. Pleae tell me. i will do it as you say.

Comment: @Arjun: You must learn a library before you can use it. Again, don't bother learning AWT but instead learn Swing, you can Google for the Oracle Swing tutorials, and read up on how to use layout managers and all the other details.